# Haskell How do i know GHCi is working corretly

Tags: haskell, ghci

Hi I'm a student and completely new to programming and Haskell.
I'm using a Mac 10.11.5 downloaded and installed Xcode, Command Line Tools, and the Haskell Platform and managed to find the Terminal and start the GHCi Interpreter simply by typing $ghci.

Problem is in my University documents and in The GHC documentation it says it should look like:

```
user@local:~$ ghci -W
GHCi, version 7.4.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude>
```

In my case it's just

```
Moritzs-Air:~ mm$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude>
```

I've checked ghc-pkg list. The cabal packages are installed. Is everything working correctly or do i have to load the packages somehow?

Is there any possibility for a complete noob to check that ghci is working correctly. i have to run a few simple tasks and my results are graded.

Moritz

Comment: don't worry - the reply you get is a good indication of a working install - notice the version - 7.4.1 is quite a while back - if you like you can start asking it a few questions like `5+5`, `:t "Hello"`, ...

Comment: maybe you should get back to your university and ask them to rework their material - it's not exactly wrong to recommend this but IMHO either just **stack** or [haskell for mac](https://ghcformacosx.github.io/) is a better choice (easier to install and operate)

Comment: @Carsten thx a a lot. So in the newest versions it's normal that the "loading package..." isn't displayed anymore? result to `:t "Hello` is :`"Hello" :: [Char]`is this good haha?

Comment: yes - see the `Prelude>` - it basically includes all this stuff

Comment: if you did not change you settings and add another module: `:m +Data.List` - you will see it there too: `Prelude Data.List>` - really: don't worry

Comment: @Carsten ok great :) what is stack?

Comment: the answer to that question can be quite long - it's basically a good solution to problems you will not have when starting out learning the language - the nice thing about it is that it handles much of the nasty surprises you can get and even can handle different GHC versions (it will download and set those up too) - see http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/

Comment: @Carsten do u recommend stack or haskell for mac? do i get the same results? i have to pack and send files to the university after i've done the tasks. I've entered `:m +Date.List`and came to `Prelude Date.List`what can i do know?

Comment: obviously I have no clue what your task is and since you have a running system I would stick with it (after all your university will expect it) - if you ever install it on a new system for your own fun and profit I would suggest just stack (of course if you come back in 2years ...)

Comment: @Carsten Ok. Thx a lot for everything :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those three packages ([ghc-prim](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.4.0.0/candidate/docs/GHC-Prim.html), [integer-gmp](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.4.1.0), and [base](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.4.1.0)) just don't report loading in new versions of ghci.

`base`, for example, *provides* `Prelude>` and its support libraries, so if you see it, it's loaded.